# Is there any code for showing a different modes(charging,parking,driving) of a vehicle on map?

Tags: python, pandas, leaflet, geospatial, matplotlib-basemap

I have a location data set for a vehicle including LONGITUDE,LATITUDE and MODE (charging,driving and parking) as follows:

| longitude | latitude | mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | charging |
| x | y1 | charging |
| x1 | y3 | parking |
| x2 | y2 | driving |
| x2 | y | parking |
| x1 | y4 | driving |
| x | y1 | driving |

I want to plot these modes (charging,driving and parking) in different colour markers on map using python libraries in jupyter notebook.

Expecting a map showing all the modes of vehicle in different color

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


data = [['x', 'y', 'charging'], ['x', 'y1', 'charging'], ['x1', 'y3', 'parking'], ['x2', 'y2', 'driving'], ['x2', 'y', 'parking'], ['x1', 'y4', 'driving'], ['x', 'y1', 'driving']]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Log', 'Lat', 'Mode'])
final_data = data.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)


cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
modes = np.array(final_data['Mode'])
modes_unique = np.unique(modes)
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(modes_unique)))
colors_ = [colors[i] for i in modes]

plt.scatter(data['Log'], data['Lat'], c=colors_)
plt.plot()
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: OP need `I want to plot these modes (charging,driving and parking) in different colour markers on map using python libraries in jupyter notebook.`

Comment: getting this  error:     "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"